# How to get select option in AmStock chart

Tags: android, amcharts

Select option is working fine in Desktop

Image:
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnyj7yp8u404z19/Screenshot%20from%202014-02-17%2017%3A29%3A08.png]

but How to get this option in Android 4.4.2 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set chart.panEventsEnabled = true; or panEventsEnabled:true if you are using JSON config.

Comment: i got little different effect after apply "chart.panEventsEnabled = true" ..
now i can click on graph point in Android 4.0 > but still can't select datapoint as above image !

Comment: i found there is bug in Amchart lib which provided in my bundle !!

Comment: What kind of bug? I suggest moving to amcharts support area.

Comment: i Aready raised ticket on this context..
problem is entire Amchart*.js file which provided in my bundle..
i don't know which is exactly file.. but 100% sure problem is Amchart*.js file.. for testing i just include free version of Amchart*.js file directly from their site and problem was gone..

Comment: problem solved now.. there was bug in Amchart (stock.js) file.. which is fixed in V3.4.4
thanks